# Página não funciona no chrome

Tags: html5, css3, bootstrap-3

Fiz uma página de cadastro, mas no chrome nao mostra o css atualizado dela, mas pelo firefox mostra tudo atualizado já. Aí eu subi no servidor pra ver pelo meu celular, iphone 5s, e mesmo assim não funciona corretamente, fica faltando coisas que mexi pelo css, e eu subi TUDO. E as vezes quando eu apago o cache do chrome, o site fica atualizado com todo o css que eu coloquei.

Página:

```
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- As 3 meta tags acima *devem* vir em primeiro lugar dentro do `head`; qualquer outro conteúdo deve vir *após* essas tags -->
    <title>Lojas Guido | Portal do Cliente - Cadastro</title>

    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:300,400,700" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" media="all">
    <link rel="icon" href="img/icon/guido.ico" type="image/x-icon">
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" media="all">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/footer.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/footerIndex/Media_Query_FooterCadastro.css">

    <script src="js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>

  </head>

          <body>

          <div id="header">
            <div id="retngulo-3-cad"></div>
            <div id="forma-1"></div>
          </div>

    <br>

        <h1 class="portal portal_cadastro"><span class="degrade">Portal guido</span></h1>

    <!-- CADASTRO -->
          <div class="container">
            <div class="row-fluid">
              <div class="col-xs-12 col-lg-12">

                <div class="form-cadastro">

                      <h2 class="degrade">cadastro</h2>
                      <br>
                      <?php
                        include "config/processa.php";
                       ?>
                            <form method="POST">
                          <label class="cor">CPF*:</label>
                          <span>Apenas números</span>
                            <input type="text" id="cpf" name="cpf" title="Digite apenas números" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="00000000000" maxlength="11" required /><span id="resposta"></span>

                              <br>

                          <label inputemail>E-mail*:</label>
                            <input type="email" id="email" name="email" class="form-control input-lg email" placeholder="SeuEmail@Email.com" maxlength="50" required />

                              <br>

                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block" id="cadastrar" name="cadastrar" disbled/ >
                              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span>
                              <span id="cpf"></span>Cadastrar</button>
                              <br>
                              <span>Já possui cadastro?</span>  <a href="index.php" class="cadastro">Login</a>

                              <ul id="page-bar">
                                <br>
                                <li><a href="#" target="_blank">Lojas Guido</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#" class="faceb" target="_blank">Facebook</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#" class="mapa" target="_blank">Mapa</a></li>

                              </ul>

                            </form>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

    <!-- FIM CADASTRO -->

    <!-- RODAPÉ -->
    <div class="div-2"></div>

    <br>
        <div class="footer_complete">
             <div class="bt-1 py-4 text-center text-md-left bg-inverse">
               <div class="container">
                 <div class="row">
                   <div class="col-md-12 ">
                     <div class="row">
                     <div class="col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-sm-4">
                         <h3 class="mb-1  text-white  m-0 display-3">Informações</h3>
                         <ul class="list-unstyled text-white mb">
                           <li>
                             <a href="#" class="link-1" >Termos de Uso</a>
                           </li>
                           <li>
                             <a href="#" class="link-1">Ofertas</a>
                           </li>
                           <li>
                             <a href="#" class="link-1">Como Funciona</a>
                           </li>
                         </ul>
                       </div>
                       <!---->

                       <!---->
                       <div class="col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-sm-4">
                         <h3 class="mb-1 text-white  m-0 display-3">Contate-nos</h3>
                         <ul class="list-unstyled  text-white">
                           <li class="text-warning">guidoportal@lojasguido.com.br</li>
                           <li class="text-warning"> (82) 3217-6300 </li>
                           <li class="text-warning"> Esc. Central: Rua do Comércio, 155,</li>
                           <li class="text-warning">Centro - Maceió - Alagoas</li>
                         </ul>
                       </div>
                       <!---->
                       <div class="col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-sm-4">
                         <h3 class="mb-1 text-white  m-0 display-3">Redes Sociais</h3>
                         <ul class="list-unstyled  text-white">
                           <li>
                             <a href="https://www.facebook.com/lojasguido" class="link-1" target="_blank">Facebook</a>
                           </li>
                           <li>
                             <a href="http://www.twitter.com/lojasguido" class="link-1" target="_blank">Twitter</a>
                           </li>
                           <li>
                             <a href="https://www.youtube.com/user/lojasguido" class="link-1" target="_blank">Youtube</a>
                           </li>
                         </ul>
                       </div>
                     </div>
                   </div>
                 </div>
                 <!--Copyright-->
                 <div class="row text-white">
                   <div class="col-md-12 col-lg-12  col-sm-12 text-right copyright">
                   <p class="mt-1">Todos os direitos reservados. |
                       &copy; 2018 Loja.</p>
                   </div>
                 </div>
               </div>
             </div>
        </div>
      </body>
    </html>
```

CSS:

```
#forma-1 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0.5px;
    left: 0%;
    width: 100%;
    height: 1px ;
    z-index: 880;
    background-color: #326895;
    right: 0%;
    margin: auto;
}

#retngulo-3 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: -580px;
    width: 149px;
    height: 3.5px;
    z-index: 890;
    background-color: #3293b7;
    right: 484.3px;
    margin: auto;
}

#retngulo-3-cad{
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 500px;
  width: 149px;
  height: 3.5px;
  z-index: 890;
  background-color: #3293b7;
  right: 484.3px;
  margin: auto;
}
#header {
    position: absolute;
    top: 30px;
    left: 0%;
    width: 100%;
    height: 59px;
    z-index: 870;
    right: 0%;
    margin: auto;
}
.cadastro{
  font-size: 18px;
  color: #bac7d3;
  /* text-decoration:underline; */
}

.cadastro:hover,
.cadastro:focus{
  color: #a1a7ad;
}

#page-bar {
 /* margin: 0px;
padding: 0px; */
width:400px;
}
#page-bar ul {
/* width: 200%; */
}
#page-bar li {
float:left;
display:block;
list-style-position: inside;
list-style-image: none;
list-style-type: none;
margin: 0px;
padding: 0px;
}
#page-bar li a{
color: #bac7d3;
display:block;
width: 87px;
text-align: center;
position: relative;
right: 28px;
font-size: 15px;
padding-top: 5px;
padding-bottom: 5px;
}

#page-bar li a:hover,
#page-bar li a:focus{
    color: #a1a7ad;
}
.faceb{
  position: relative;
  left: -18px;
}

.citacao-bio {
    /* background-color: #D9E5E3;
    border: .5em solid #C2CCCA; */
    padding: 1em;
    margin: 1em 2em;
    width: 50ch;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    transition: box-shadow 1s, transform 1s;
    transition-delay: 1s, 0s;
}

.degrade{
  font-weight: bold;
  text-transform:uppercase;

  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#696969, #000000);
 -webkit-background-clip: text;
 -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
}

.portal_cadastro{
  text-align: center;
}

.logo{
  float: right;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: bold;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#3293b7, #3293b7, #326895, #326895);
 -webkit-background-clip: text;
 -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
}

.div-1{
  padding: 200px;
}

.div-2{
  padding: 100px;
}

/*IPHONE 5 */
@media only screen
  and (device-width : 320px)
  and (device-height : 568px){
    #retngulo-3-cad{
      left: 86px;
    }

    #page-bar li a{
    right: 60px;
    }

    .faceb{
      position: relative;
      left: -55px;
    }
    #page-bar{
      width: 130%;
    }
    .mapa{
      position: relative;
      left: 120%;
      bottom: 31px;
    }
    .mt-1{
      position: relative;
      left: 1.2em;
      top: 1em;
      text-align: center;
      width: 87%;
    }
}
/*FIM IPHONE 5 */

/*IPHONE 4 */
@media only screen
  and (device-width : 320px)
  and (device-height : 480px){
    #retngulo-3-cad{
      left: 86px;
    }

    #page-bar li a{
    right: 60px;
    }

    .faceb{
      position: relative;
      left: -55px;
    }
    #page-bar{
      width: 130%;
    }
    .mapa{
      position: relative;
      left: 120%;
      bottom: 31px;
    }
    .mt-1{
      position: relative;
      left: 1.2em;
      top: 1em;
      text-align: center;
      width: 87%;
    }
}
/*FIM IPHONE 4 */

/*IPHONE 6 */
@media only screen
  and (device-width : 375px)
  and (device-height : 667px){
    #retngulo-3-cad{
      left: 115px;
    }

    #page-bar li a{
    right: 45px;
    }

    .faceb{
      position: relative;
      left: -32px;
    }
    #page-bar{
      width: 125%;
    }
    .mapa{
      position: relative;
      left: -2.5em;
    }
    .mt-1{
      position: relative;
      left: 3em;
      top: 1em;
      text-align: center;
      width: 72%;
    }
}
/*FIM IPHONE 6 */

/*IPHONE 6s plus */
@media only screen
  and (device-width : 414px)
  and (device-height : 736px){
    #retngulo-3-cad{
      left: 135px;
    }
    #page-bar li a{
    right: 30px;
    }

    .faceb{
      position: relative;
      left: -16px;
    }
    #page-bar{
      width: 120%;
    }
    .mapa{
      position: relative;
      left: -1em;
    }
    .mt-1{
      position: relative;
      left: 5em;
      top: 1em;
      text-align: center;
      width: 60%;
    }
}
/*FIM IPHONE 6s plus */

/*GOOGLE NEXUS 4 */
@media only screen
  and (device-width : 384px)
  and (device-height : 640px){
    #retngulo-3-cad{
      left: 135px;
    }
    #page-bar li a{
    right: 50px;
    }

    .faceb{
      position: relative;
      left: -27px;
    }
    #page-bar{
      width: 120%;
    }
    .mapa{
      position: relative;
      left: -1em;
    }
    .mt-1{
      position: relative;
      left: 3.5em;
      top: 1em;
      text-align: center;
      width: 70%;
    }
}
/*FIM GOOGLE NEXUS 4 */

/*GOOGLE NEXUS 5 */
@media only screen
  and (device-width : 360px)
  and (device-height : 640px){
    #retngulo-3-cad{
      left: 8em;
    }
    #page-bar li a{
    right: 50px;
    }

    .faceb{
      position: relative;
      left: -38px;
    }
    #page-bar{
      width: 120%;
    }
    .mapa{
      position: relative;
      left: 9em;
      bottom: 2.02em;
    }
    .mt-1{
      position: relative;
      left: 3.5em;
      top: 1em;
      text-align: center;
      width: 71%;
    }
}
/*FIM GOOGLE NEXUS 5 */

/*GOOGLE NEXUS 6 */
@media only screen
  and (device-width : 412px)
  and (device-height : 732px){
    #retngulo-3-cad{
      left: 10em;
    }
    #page-bar li a{
    right: 50px;
    }

    .faceb{
      position: relative;
      left: -1em;
    }
    #page-bar{
      width: 120%;
    }
    .mapa{
      position: relative;
      left: 0em;
      bottom: 0em;
    }
    .mt-1{
      position: relative;
      left: 4.5em;
      top: 1em;
      text-align: center;
      width: 64%;
    }
}
/*FIM GOOGLE NEXUS 6 */

/*GOOGLE NEXUS 7 */
@media only screen
  and (device-width : 960px)
  and (device-height : 600px){
    #retngulo-3-cad{
      left: 29em;
    }
    #page-bar li a{
    right: 39px;
    }

    .faceb{
      position: relative;
      left: -1em;
    }
    #page-bar{
      width: 120%;
    }
    .mapa{
      position: relative;
      left: 0em;
      bottom: 0em;
    }
    .mt-1{
      position: relative;
      left: 7em;
    }
}
/*FIM GOOGLE NEXUS 7 */

/*MOTOROLA MOTO 360 */
@media only screen
  and (device-width : 320px)
  and (device-height : 290px){
    #retngulo-3-cad{
      left: 6em;
    }
    #page-bar li a{
    right: 4em;
    }

    .faceb{
      position: relative;
      left: -3.7em;
    }
    #page-bar{
      width: 120%;
    }
    .mapa{
      position: relative;
      left: 7em;
      bottom: 2.08em;
    }
    .mt-1{
      position: relative;
      left: 2em;
      width: 85%;
      text-align: center;
    }
}
/*FIM MOTOROLA MOTO 360 */

/*IPAD AIR 2*/
@media only screen
  and (device-width : 1024px)
  and (device-height : 768px){
    #retngulo-3-cad{
      left: 32em;
    }
    #page-bar li a{
    right: 2em;
    }

    .faceb{
      position: relative;
      left: -1em;
    }
    #page-bar{
      width: 120%;
    }
    .mapa{
      position: relative;
      left: -1em;
      bottom: 0em;
    }
    .mt-1{
      position: relative;
      width: 100%;
    }
}
/*FIM IPAD AIR 2*/
```

Comment: Marina mesmo sendo grande coloque o seu HTML inteiro! E o CSS também!! Sem isso é pouco provável que a gente consiga simular o seu erro e te dar uma resposta.

Comment: @hugocsl Pronto. Coloquei todo html e todo css

Comment: Cade o `<head>` da sua página? Ela começa direto do `<body>` ??

Comment: Ela tem o <head> mas nao coloquei pq achei desnecessário, mas se caso precisar eu coloco

Comment: Maria deixa eu te explicar pq eu pedi o `<head>` normalmente é nele que nos incluímos as folhas de estilo, os CDNs de Bootstrap etc, e ali costuma dar alguns erros de indexação, etc. Agora com o código completo e sabendo o que vc indexou na página fica melhor para te dar uma resposta.

Comment: Ah, sim. Já coloquei tudo completo agora então